# Using treeview as a listbox to add rows in database

Tags: python, function, treeview, row, instance

Im making a prescription management app i have 2 classes Presman which i include the gui making methods the Newpreswin class where i call functions from presman to create the data entry gui one of them is def create_treeview: where im using as a listbox to insert rows in a database

class NewpresWin(tk.Toplevel):
def **init**(self, parent, frames, entryfields, labels,calendars,functions=None, closing_event=None):
super().**init**(parent)
self.parent=parent
self.functions=functions if functions else Functions(self)
self.presman = Presman(self)

#... other methods and values
self.presman.create_treeview(display_data=False) #i call the method from presman and clear he values
#... other methods

class Presman:
# Initializes main window
def **init**(self, master):
self.master = master
self.functions=Functions(self)

#... other values and methods
self.create_treeview() #this method creates treeview in the presman class
#other methods

because the code was getting unmanageble with so many rows i split my code the one that already provided in gui.py and the other called functions.py in functions.py i have a method which adds the rows in the treeview before i move them in the database when i called def add_med this method is used to insert the rows in the treeview which is displayed in the NewpesWin window but when i call the method instead of adding the data in the treeview in the newpreswin the method adds them in the treeview in the presman window before i split the code everything was working fine

this is the method i am describing it is in the file functions.py

class Functions:
def **init**(self, Presman):
self.presman = Presman

## Adds row with medicine in newpreswin treeview

```
def add_med(self):
    # Define a function to handle opening the Presscan file when a row is double-clicked on Treeview
    def on_select(event):
        item = self.newpreswin.treeview.selection()
        if item:
            # Get the value of the Presscan column for the selected row
            presscan_value = self.newpreswin.treeview.item(item, 'values')[10]
            if presscan_value:
                # Open the file with webbrowser
                webbrowser.open(presscan_value)
            else:
                messagebox.showerror('Error', 'No file associated with this row.', parent=self.presman.frames['center_frame'])
    
    # Read the values of the entry fields and get the corresponding directories
    phaident = self.presman.entryfields['phaident'].get().strip()
    medicent = self.presman.entryfields['medicent'].get().strip()
    barcode = self.presman.entryfields['barcdent'].get().strip()
    uppic = self.presman.labels['uploadlabel'].cget('text')
    
    # Check if any of the fields are empty
    if not barcode:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Barcode field is empty.', parent=self.presman.frames['center_frame'])
        self.presman.entryfields['barcdent'].focus_set()
        return

    if not phaident:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Pharmacy ID field is empty.', parent=self.presman.frames['center_frame'])
        self.presman.entryfields['phaident'].focus_set()
        return
    if not medicent:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Medicine field is empty.', parent=self.presman.frames['center_frame'])
        self.presman.entryfields['medicent'].focus_set()
        return
    if not uppic:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Please upload the prescription.', parent=self.presman.frames['center_frame'])
        return
    
    # Look for the pharmacy directory
    pha_dir = os.path.join('c:', os.sep, 'presman', 'Data', phaident)
    if not os.path.isdir(pha_dir):
        messagebox.showerror(f"Pharmacy directory {pha_dir} not found", parent=self.presman.frames['center_frame'])
    
    # Create the medicine directory if it doesn't exist
    med_dir = os.path.join(pha_dir, medicent)
    if not os.path.isdir(med_dir):
        os.mkdir(med_dir)
    
    # Check if the file exists in the Temp directory
    temp_dir = os.path.join('c:', os.sep, 'presman', 'Data', 'Temp')
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"{barcode}.jpg")
    if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
        messagebox.showerror(f"File {barcode}.jpg not found in {temp_dir}", parent=self.presman.frames['center_frame'])
    
    # Copy the file to the medicine directory
    med_file = os.path.join(med_dir, f"{barcode}.jpg")
    shutil.copyfile(file_path, med_file)
    
    # Fetch the last inserted Cntr value from the database and increment the treeview index by 1
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(Cntr) FROM data")
    last_Cntr = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
    if last_Cntr is None:
        Cntr = 1
    else:
        Cntr = last_Cntr + 1
    
    if hasattr(self, 'current_index'):
        self.current_index + 1
    else:
        self.current_index = 0
    
    Cntr += self.current_index
    
    # Set the values for the new row
    Barcode = barcode
    Pharmacy = self.presman.labels['phaidreslabel'].cget("text")
    Medicine = medicent
    Qnt = self.presman.entryfields['quantent'].get()
    Pres = self.presman.calendars['presdate'].get_date()
    Exp = self.presman.calendars['expdate'].get_date()
    Comment = self.presman.entryfields['ucomment'].get()
    User = open('userlog.txt', 'r').read().strip()
    Timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    Presscan = med_file

    # Update the Presscan column in the Treeview widget
    self.newpreswin.treeview.set(self.newpreswin.treeview.selection(), 'Presscan', med_file)

    # Insert the new row into the Treeview widget
    self.newpreswin.treeview.insert('', 'end', values=(Cntr, Barcode, Pharmacy, Medicine, Qnt, Pres, Exp, Comment, User, Timestamp, Presscan), tags=('clickable',))

    # Clear the medicent and quantent fields
    self.presman.entryfields['medicent'].delete(0, 'end')
    self.presman.entryfields['quantent'].delete(0, 'end')
    self.newpreswin.treeview.bind('<Double-Button-1>', on_select)
```

the method was working just fine until i split the code
i have created all the necessary instances and other methods are working as expected except this one